# Can you have an Azure Data Lake gen2 without HNS?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake

I'm trying to understand our options in creating a Azure Data Lake.  I understand from [this article](https://www.blue-granite.com/blog/10-things-to-know-about-azure-data-lake-storage-gen2) that a gen2 data lake is basically an Azure V2 storage account with Hns enabled.  I take it from this that there's no such thing as a gen2 data lake without Hns enabled.  Is that so?  Also, is there any such thing as a data lake gen1 with Hns?

Comment: ADLS gen 2 without hierarchical namespace is just a regular storage account, without everything that comes with HNS. As for ADLS gen 1, there is great documentation describing its feature set and HDFS.

Comment: Yes, if you want to use ADLS gen2, you must set hns. And for ADLS gen1, it already have this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I take it from this that there's no such thing as a gen2 data lake
>   without Hns enabled.

Yes, there is no such thing as gen2 data lake without hns. If you want to use ADLS gen2, you must set that.

This is the doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-create?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json&tabs=azure-portal#create-a-storage-account

‎Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 is a set of capabilities dedicated to big data analytics, built on Azure Blob storage. Data Lake Storage Gen2 is the result of converging the capabilities of two existing storage services, Azure Blob storage and Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1.

If you plan to use Azure Data Lake Storage, you should choose the Advanced tab when you create azure v2 storage account, and then set Hierarchical namespace to Enabled. After the v2 storage account has been created, you cannot change this options any more.(This is the way how to create ADLS gen2.)

> is there any such thing as a data lake gen1 with Hns?

The ADLS gen1 already have this feature. Please have a look of this doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-migrate-gen1-to-gen2#gen1-vs-gen2-capabilities

Comment: Still strange that the pricing calculator gives a flat namespace as default despite selecting type "Data Lake Storage Gen2". This seems misleading to me. I hope it's a bug and not intentional.